# Count elements in data in a XML URL using XSL and printing in html

Tags: html, node.js, xml, xslt

I have a XML URL[1](http://vhost11.lnu.se:20090/final/getFilterData.php?parameter=User_IDpatient&value=3).
My output needs to be something like

- 2009-12-01: 2
- 2009-12-02: 2

I am trying to achieve this using XSL (this is my first time using it, so my code can look really silly).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <xsl:copy-of select="document('http://vhost11.lnu.se:20090/final/getFilterData.php?parameter=User_IDpatient&value=3')/EData/test_sessionID"/> 
    2009-12-01 :   <xsl:value-of select="count(EData/test_sessionID[test_datetime=2009-12-01 18:00:00])" />
    2009-12-02 :   <xsl:value-of select="count(EData/test_sessionID[test_datetime=2009-12-02 18:00:00])" />
</body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Even if this code works, there are couple of issues like the date and time stamp is merged. Ideally the count has to be done only on the date part of the test_datetime element. The other is how to get the date automatically instead of writing it manually.

I am using node.js as my server. I don't get any errors either in console or Chrome's developer tools. So, a little lost on how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [camaro](https://www.npmjs.com/package/camaro) for this

```
const transform = require('camaro')
const rp = require('request-promise')

rp('http://vhost11.lnu.se:20090/final/getFilterData.php?parameter=User_IDpatient&value=3')
    .then(xml => {
        return transform(xml, {
            '2009-12-01': 'count(//test_datetime[text() = "2009-12-01 18:00:00"])',
            '2009-12-02': 'count(//test_datetime[text() = "2009-12-02 18:00:00"])'
        })
    })
    .then(console.log)
```

Output

```
{ '2009-12-01': 2, '2009-12-02': 2 }
```

In case you want to capture the date automatically without specifying manually, you can do this

```
const transform = require('camaro')
const rp = require('request-promise')
const _ = require('lodash')

rp('http://vhost11.lnu.se:20090/final/getFilterData.php?parameter=User_IDpatient&value=3')
    .then(xml => {
        return transform(xml, {
            data: ['//test_datetime', {
                value: './text()'
            }]
        })
    })
    .then(json => _.groupBy(json.data, 'value'))
    .then(grps => _.mapValues(grps, 'length'))
    .then(console.log)
```

Output

```
{ '2009-12-01 18:00:00': 2, '2009-12-02 18:00:00': 2 }
```

Comment: Hello Tuan, This is very interesting. But I need to display this data in a html. How do I do that? Do I need to use app.get to send this data to front end? Isn't it better to do it directly on the client side?

Comment: you can pass the data anywhere. it's just js object.